# Cargar Datatable a partir de una consulta en Django

Tags: django, datatable

Estoy en un proyecto en el cual tengo un modelo creado `CtaAcreedores` en donde almaceno todas las compras que realice a un proveedor específico. Luego tengo un formulario con dos input donde ingreso fecha desde y fecha hasta, además un select donde elijo un Proveedor específico. Lo que quiero es hacer una consulta al modelo `CtaAcreedores` filtrando por proveedor y por rango de fecha y este resultado mostrarlo en un DataTable.

```
class CtaAcreedores(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha', blank= True)
    letra = models.CharField(max_length= 1, verbose_name= 'Letra', blank= True)
    sucursal = models.DecimalField (max_digits= 4, decimal_places=0, verbose_name='Sucursal', blank= True)
    nro_comprobante = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, verbose_name = 'Numero', blank = True)
    tpo_comprobante = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name='Tipo Comprobante', blank= True)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length= 80, verbose_name= 'Comentario', null = True, blank = True)
    debe = models.FloatField(verbose_name= 'Debe', default= 0.00, null = True, blank = True)
    haber = models.FloatField(verbose_name= 'Haber', default= 0.00, null = True, blank = True)
    # FK
    cod_proveedor =  models.ForeignKey(Proveedores, verbose_name='Cod. Prov.', default = None, on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tpo_comprobante + " " + self.letra + " " + str(self.sucursal) + "-" + str(self.nro_comprobante)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuentas_acreedores'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya Muchisimas gracias.!!!

view.py

```
class ListadoMovimientosProveedor(ListView):
    model = CtaAcreedores
    template_name ='compras/proveedores/movimientos_proveedores.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        if self.is_ajax(request):
            data = serialize('json', self.model.objects.all(), use_natural_foreign_keys = True)
            return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'proveedores': Proveedores.objects.filter(estado = True)})

    def is_ajax(self, request):
        return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

movimientos_proveedores.html

```
<form method="GET" action ="" id='mov_prov'>
                                
                                <div class = 'card mb-4 d-flex'>
                                    <div class = 'row'>
                                        <div class = 'col-12'>
                                            
                                            <div class = 'row'>

                                                <div id="date_filter" class = 'row mt-3'>
                                                    <div class = 'col-2'>
                                                        <span id="date-label-from" class="date-label ml-3">DESDE: </span>
                                                        <input class="text-center form-control ml-3" type="date" name='desde' id="min" placeholder='DD/MM/AAAA' style = 'height:47%; width:110%'/>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class = 'col-2'>
                                                        <span id="date-label-to" class="date-label ml-4">HASTA: </span>
                                                        <input class="text-center form-control ml-4" type="date" name='hasta' id="max" placeholder='DD/MM/AAAA' style = 'height:47%; width:110%'/>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class = 'col-6 ml-5 mb-3'>
                                                        <span id="date-label-from" class="date-label ml-1">PROVEEDOR: </span>
                                                       
                                                        <select name="cod_proveedor" class="select2 custom-select mb-4 ml-3" id="id_cod_prov" data-select2-id="select2-data-id_cod_caja">
                                                            <option value="" selected id="">---------</option>
                                                            {% for proveedor in proveedores %}
                                                                <option value="{{proveedor.nombre}}" id="">{{proveedor.nombre}}</option>
                                                            {% endfor %}
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        
                                        </div>  
                                        
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Hasta ahora la solucion que se me ocurrio es por medio de JQuery:

```
function listado_mov_proveedores(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/compras/listado_movimientos_proveedor/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            
            //Función que carga los datos en datatable dependiendo del select 'id_cod_proveedor'
            cargar_tabla($("#id_cod_proveedor option:selected").val(), response);
            
            // Instancia del datatable
            var table = $('#tabla_mov_proveedor').DataTable();

            // Cuando se cambie la fecha en el input #min y #max dibuja nuevamente la tabla con el rango de fecha   
            $('#min').on('change', function () {
                var opcion_prov = $("#id_cod_prov option:selected").val();
                cargar_tabla(opcion_prov, response);
            });

            $('#max').on('change',function () {
                var opcion_prov = $("#id_cod_prov option:selected").val();
                cargar_tabla(opcion_prov, response);
            });

            // Cuando cambiemos la opción del select cargara el datatable dependiendo de esa opción
            $("#id_cod_prov").on('change', function(){
                var opcion_prov = $("#id_cod_prov option:selected").val();
                cargar_tabla(opcion_prov, response);
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        },
    })
}

// Función que se llama cuando el documento ya esta listo. Es decir, cuando ya cargo la pagina.
$(document).ready(function(){
    listado_mov_proveedores();
});

function cargar_tabla(cod_prov, response){
    var saldo = 0;
    // Si existe una instancia de DataTable con el id 'tabla_mov_proveedor' entonces que la destruya
    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tabla_mov_proveedor')){
        $('#tabla_mov_proveedor').DataTable().destroy();
    };

    $('#tabla_mov_proveedor tbody').html(""); // Me aseguro que el cuerpo del DataTable esta vacio
    
    // Llenamos el datatable con los datos del modelo
    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        if(response[i]['fields']['cod_proveedor'] === cod_prov){
            if(response[i]['fields']['fecha'] >= $('#min').val() && response[i]['fields']['fecha'] <= $('#max').val()){
                saldo = saldo + response[i]['fields']['debe'] - response[i]['fields']['haber'];
                var fila = '<tr>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['fecha'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['tpo_comprobante'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['letra'] + ' ' + response[i]['fields']['sucursal'] + '-' + response[i]['fields']['nro_comprobante'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['comentario'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['debe'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + response[i]['fields']['haber'] + '</td>';
                fila += '<td>' + saldo + '</td>';
                fila += '</tr>';
            }
        } 
        $('#tabla_mov_proveedor tbody').append(fila);
    };
    $('#tabla_mov_proveedor').DataTable({
        language: {
            "decimal": "",
            "emptyTable": "No hay información",
            "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
            "infoEmpty": "Sin datos",
            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total de entradas",
            "infoPostFix": "",
            "thousands": ",",
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar",
            "zeroRocords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primero",
                "last": "Ultimo",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
        },
        // Personalizar columnas 
        columnDefs:[
            
            {"targets": 0,
             render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) // Renderiza las fechas con el formato especificado

            },

            {"targets": [1],
             "className": "text-center"
            },

            {"targets": [4,5,6], // Hace referencia a las columnas donde 0 es la primer columna.
             "className": "text-right", // Class de bootstrap que alinea el texto a la derecha.
             render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' ) // renderiza los números como moneda.
            },
            
        ],
        //"searching": true,
        scrollX: true,
        responsive: true,
        // Formatea los dos inputs que filtran la fecha
        initComplete: function () {
            
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Y que has logrado hasta ahora? El código del modelo es parte esencial para generar la consulta pero no relevante con respecto a tu pregunta. Necesitas que te proporcionemos una consulta pero no muestras que intentos has hecho por resolverlo! Sube el mas minimo codigo que has intentado, asi como la funcion de tu view que se encargara se retornar los datos.

Comment: De igual manera coloca el codigo de tu form, para tener una visual de los campos requeridos: (asumiendo que las fechas pueden estar vacías ambas, o solo una de ellas) y cual  seria el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Mil disculpas, ahi acabo de poner un poco mas de codigo. Muchas gracias!